# В чём подвох Comodo Positive SSL (типа 3 года за 15 баксов)?

Tags: ssl

Я в этих сертификатах не разбираюсь. Думаю этот купить.
И чем он от этого отличается? -> https://letsencrypt.org/ (этот бесплатный вроде, но на короткий срок и надо продлевать)

Comment: Что один, что другой - туфта. И если они продолжат раздачу сертов всем подряд - скоро им перестанут доверять.

Comment: LetsEncrypt надо каждые 3 месяца продлевать. Про отличия: [Comodo Positive SSL и Let’s Encrypt: плюсы и минусы](http://timeweb.com/ru/community/articles/comodo-positive-ssl-i-let-s-encrypt-plyusy-i-minusy-1) и табличкой: [Сравнение Let’s Encrypt ssl и Comodo Positive ssl сертификатов](https://support.hostpro.ua/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/405/78/sravnenie-lets-encrypt-ssl-i-comodo-positive-ssl-sertifikatov)

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, почему? И если сейчас идёт тенденция, что всё должно быть через https (тот же http2 принципиально не работает с http), то где куча народу с блогами должна брать сертификаты? Это же просто гарантия зашифрованности соединения - какие причины не доверять выдающему центру, если он всё честно выдаёт?

Comment: @Qwertiy а как можно выдать нечестно? и что за фигня с 3 месяцами? типа выдать левому сайту. а 3 месяца это как раз косвенная проверка и отсев всяких ворюг

Comment: @Hipster, нечестно - это выдать сертификат не владельцу сайта, а какому-то мошеннику, что он сможет под этот сайт маскироваться. Я имел в виду, что они выдают владельцу, соответственно вредя от этого нет.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов это вряд ли. А вот что начнут уделять больше внимания EV/DV, это наверняка.